# How to seperate state, city, zipcode,contry etc. from address string?

Tags: android, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I want to separate street, city, state, country, zip code

```
String = Kanaka, Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India

public class Test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(" Kanaka, Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"); 
        System.out.println("Tokens are seperated");
        int i=0;
        String street,city,state,zipcode,country;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {

                if(i==0)
                {
                        street = st.nextToken(",");
                   System.out.println("street ="+street);
                   i++;
                }
                else if(i==1)
                {
                       city = st.nextToken(",");
                        System.out.println("city= "+city);
                        i++;
                }
                else if(i==2)
                {
                       state = st.nextToken(",");
                        System.out.println("state ="+state);
                        i++;
                }
                else if(i==3)
                {
                        zipcode = st.nextToken(",");
                        System.out.println("zipcode= "+zipcode);
                            i++;
                }
                else if(i==4)
                {
                        contry = st.nextToken(",");
                        System.out.println("country= "+country);
                        i++;
                }

        }

    }
}
```

output is :

```
06-23 09:23:37.070: INFO/System.out(435): street = Kanaka
06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): city=  Ranchi
06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): state = zalkhand
06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): zipcode=  10001
06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): country=  India
```

Above code is work fine with String "Kanaka, Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"

My problem is I parse address string from xml  which is not good format

```
ex. 1) "Kanaka, Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"

    2) "Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"   ---> kanaka(street is absent )
```

output :
    06-23 09:23:37.070: INFO/System.out(435): street = Ranchi
    06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): city=  zalkhand
    06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): state = 10001
    06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): zipcode=  India
    06-23 09:23:37.080: INFO/System.out(435): country=

```
    3) "zalkhand, 10001, India"
    4) Kanaka zalkhand, 10001, India" (, is missing )
```

like this

so how to separate above string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create a array and after parsing address String put the tokens in that array using StringTokenizer.But via this you won't be able to differentiate  which is City or ZIP code.
It is quite difficult so try to make XML well formated.Like if City is absent put a default value so you can use as absent field.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens and splitting are necessary but not sufficient.

Your problem is that if you encounter a multi-token item you and your program both need enough context to understand where one token ends and the next begins.

It's the same problem here in the US.  Given this address:

```
100 Main Street San Francisco CA 09654
```

Your brain has enough context to know that "San Francisco" is the city, and the state code is "CA", but how do you tell a computer program how to do it?

You need a parser that has more knowledge of what an address is.  It would help if the separators delineated where each items started and ended, so multi-token items would not be a problem.

You can solve it with a clear token delimiter:

```
100 Main Street~San Francisco~CA~09654
```

Split at the "~" and all is well.

Comment: thanks i know this but i can't change this data come from server so i can not make change in server data so please tel me another way..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a parser which should take five inputs. and replace null if some data is missing

1) "Kanaka, Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"

2) null, "Ranchi, zalkhand, 10001, India"  // if street is missing

3) "Kanaka, null, zalkhand, 10001, India"  // if city is missing

pass this type of value to your StringTokenizer.

Comment: i can not replace null instantiated of missing field because i use same XML in 10 module it hard to change all 20 module

Comment: instead of null you can use some specific special chracters

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you need a correct way of parsing the XML and all else would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

mport java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("koch, Ranchi, zalkhand, NY, 10001, India", ","); 
        int numberOfToken = st.countTokens();
        System.out.println("Tokens are seperated");
        int i=0;
        String address[] = new String[numberOfToken];

         String contlocation="";
         String contfirst_street="";
         String contsecond_street="";
         String contcity="";
         String contstate="";
         String contzipcode="";
         String contcountry="";


      /*  while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {

          */      

              for(i=0;i<numberOfToken;i++)
              {
                    address[i] = st.nextToken();
                   System.out.println("address "+i+": "+address[i]);
              }

              if(numberOfToken==7)
              {

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==7--------------------");

                  contlocation=address[0];
                  System.out.println("contlocation :"+contlocation);

                  contfirst_street=address[1];
                  System.out.println("contfirst_street :"+contfirst_street);

                  contsecond_street=address[2];
                  System.out.println("contsecond_street :"+contsecond_street);

                  contcity=address[3];
                  System.out.println("contcity :"+contcity);

                  contstate=address[4];
                  System.out.println("contstate :"+contstate);

                  contzipcode=address[5];
                  System.out.println("contzipcode :"+contzipcode);

                  contcountry=address[6];
                  System.out.println("contcountry :"+contcountry);

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==7--------------------");
              }
              else if(numberOfToken==6)
              {
                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==6--------------------");

                  contlocation="";
                  System.out.println("contlocation :"+contlocation);

                  contfirst_street=address[0];
                  System.out.println("contfirst_street :"+contfirst_street);

                  contsecond_street=address[1];
                  System.out.println("contsecond_street :"+contsecond_street);

                  contcity=address[2];
                  System.out.println("contcity :"+contcity);

                  contstate=address[3];
                  System.out.println("contstate :"+contstate);

                  contzipcode=address[4];
                  System.out.println("contzipcode :"+contzipcode);

                  contcountry=address[5];
                  System.out.println("contcountry :"+contcountry);

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==6--------------------");
              }
              else if(numberOfToken==5)
              {
                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==5--------------------");

                  contlocation="";
                  System.out.println("contlocation :"+contlocation);

                  contfirst_street=address[0];
                  System.out.println("contfirst_street :"+contfirst_street);

                  contsecond_street="";
                  System.out.println("contsecond_street :"+contsecond_street);

                  contcity=address[1];
                  System.out.println("contcity :"+contcity);

                  contstate=address[2];
                  System.out.println("contstate :"+contstate);

                  contzipcode=address[3];
                  System.out.println("contzipcode :"+contzipcode);

                  contcountry=address[4];
                  System.out.println("contcountry :"+contcountry);

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==5--------------------");
              }

              else if(numberOfToken==4)
              {
                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==4--------------------");

                  contlocation="";
                  System.out.println("contlocation :"+contlocation);

                  contfirst_street=address[0];
                  System.out.println("contfirst_street :"+contfirst_street);

                  contsecond_street="";
                  System.out.println("contsecond_street :"+contsecond_street);

                  contcity=address[1];
                  System.out.println("contcity :"+contcity);

                  contstate=address[2];
                  System.out.println("contstate :"+contstate);

                  contzipcode="";
                  System.out.println("contzipcode :"+contzipcode);

                  contcountry=address[3];
                  System.out.println("contcountry :"+contcountry);

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==4--------------------");
              }

              else if(numberOfToken==3)
              {
                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==3--------------------");

                  contlocation="";
                  System.out.println("contlocation :"+contlocation);

                  contfirst_street=address[0];
                  System.out.println("contfirst_street :"+contfirst_street);

                  contsecond_street="";
                  System.out.println("contsecond_street :"+contsecond_street);

                  contcity=address[1];
                  System.out.println("contcity :"+contcity);

                  contstate="";
                  System.out.println("contstate :"+contstate);

                  contzipcode="";
                  System.out.println("contzipcode :"+contzipcode);

                  contcountry=address[2];
                  System.out.println("contcountry :"+contcountry);

                  System.out.println("\n-------------address.length==3--------------------");
              }
}
    }
```